# If Statements with Variable Numbers

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I am working on a program and have come up with an error I don't usually face. My error is quite simple, yet I cannot wrap my head around a way to get past this problem. Thanks for helping.

Code:

```
budget = 50
depositAmount = input("Please enter an amount you would like to add")
if depositAmount > budget:
    print("Sorry, you do not have the required funds to join. You have been exited.")
else:
    #DO THE REST OF THE PROGRAM#
```

So in short terms, I will be adding values to the budget variable in the future, thats why I can't use the if statement and say less than 50, because the budget variable may be different. How do I make sure that if the user inputs a number greater than the variable value (or lower) they will be given an error message?

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: _"My error is quite simple"_. Fair enough. But you really need to share it with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `depositAmount` to number with [int built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) before comparing with `budget`, to do it replace your if condition from

```
if depositAmount > budget:
```

to

```
if int(depositAmount) > budget:
```